# MySQL Using ORDER BY On Grouped (GROUP BY) Results

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I am clearly misundersatanding something here with MySQL's GROUP BY as it is changing the order of my results.

Using this example SQL data:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `example_table` (
      `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `GROUP_NAME` text NOT NULL,
      `ORDER_COLUMN` int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;



    INSERT INTO `example_table` (`ID`, `GROUP_NAME`, `ORDER_COLUMN`) VALUES
    (NULL, '271007K240.003:10', 70),
    (NULL, '271007K240.003:10', 90),
    (NULL, '271007K240.003:10', 100),
    (NULL, '271007K240.003:10', 50),
    (NULL, '271007K240.003:10', 80),
   (NULL, '271007K240.003:10', 60);
```

Now I've created this data as an example so there would be lots of different values in the **GROUP_NAME** column., but for clairty I've just included what demonstrates the issue.

Running this very simple query, returns the highest **ORDER_COLUMN** (ID: 3) at the top as expected:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `example_table`
ORDER BY
    ORDER_COLUMN
DESC
```

However I've actually wanting to group by the column I've named here **GROUP_NAME**, sowith this in mind I was anting to do asomething like so:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `example_table`
GROUP BY
    GROUP_NAME
ORDER BY
    ORDER_COLUMN
DESC
```

Now doing this just simply returns the first row, and ignores the ORDER BY.

I then thought to achieve what I need, I would need to use a sub-query with the data pre-sorted and then the group by can just group the sub-queries data-set like so:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        `example_table`
    ORDER BY
        ORDER_COLUMN
    DESC
) AS TEMP_TABLE

GROUP BY GROUP_NAME
```

Unfortunately though, this still returns just the first row of the table. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: Read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html and reconsider what you want exactly.

Answer (score 1):

With this query:

```
select group_name, max(order_column) order_column
from example_table
group by group_name
```

you can get the max value of `order_column` for each `id`.
Then join it to the table:

```
select t.* 
from example_table t inner join ( 
  select group_name, max(order_column) order_column
  from example_table
  group by group_name
) g on g.group_name = t.group_name and g.order_column = t.order_column
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o7gfyJL1QB6oHSrcoWSM4T/0).
Results:

```
| ID  | GROUP_NAME        | ORDER_COLUMN |
| --- | ----------------- | ------------ |
| 3   | 271007K240.003:10 | 100          |
```

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what you want to accomplish, but did you try:

```
ORDER BY
    GROUP_NAME,
    ORDER_COLUMN
```

If that doesn't do the trick, how about adding more data with different group names and an example of what you expect the output to look like

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

By adding this example shown above I.E groupingo n the field I was I received an error due to it not being aggregated data.

Now, when grouping, the end game is to seata set here:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/poNVD1jUkdL4eNqfPqVgQW/0

So, in this example, I have added two grouBy using the GROUP BY I was hoping to be able to retrieve only 2 rows from the database, one for each of the groups. Ths I want to retrieve are the rows with the highest ORDER_COLUMN values, hence me trying the GROUP BY and ORDER By together.